# Passing variables when rendering templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables

In my forum, reply_to and quoted variables are passed into the new post page, enabling replies and quotes very nicely. The problem comes in when the user does something wrong; for instance, if the post is too short, the controller renders 'posts/new' with a flash error.

I cannot for the life of me get the controller to pass these upon rendering. Here's my setup.

Both variables are initialized in the new method:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new

  init_quoted
  init_reply_to

  if @quoted
    @post.content = "[quote="+@quoted.user.name+"]"+@quoted.content+"[/quote]"
  end
end

def init_reply_to
  if params[:reply_to]
    @reply_to = Discussion.find(params[:reply_to])
  end
end

def init_quoted
  if params[:quoted]
    @quoted = Post.find(params[@quote])
  end
end
```

This works great when the user makes no mistakes. From the "else" onward in the following code, however, variables aren't getting passed:

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])

  if @post.save
    flash[:success] = "You reply has been added."
    redirect_to controller: 'discussions', action: 'show', id: @post.discussion.id, anchor: 'post'+@post.id.to_s
  else
    render template: 'posts/new', locals: { reply_to: @reply_to, quoted: @quoted }
  end
end
```

Am I missing something? The variables should be global, so why aren't they being transferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you don't call your init functions in `create`

This should work :

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])

  if @post.save
    flash[:success] = "You reply has been added."
    redirect_to controller: 'discussions', action: 'show', id: @post.discussion.id, anchor: 'post'+@post.id.to_s
  else
    init_quoted
    init_reply_to
    render template: 'posts/new'
  end
end
```

No need to specify them as locals, just access them as `@quoted` and `@reply_to` in the view

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. It still acts as though the variables haven't been defined at all, giving an error page complaining about one of the variables being nil.

Comment: Ok that's because your init function are requiring specific params to get the values from the DB ... make sure you have the required params in the create action to get them from the DB!

Comment: It's late here and I'm having a bit of a mental block... how could I transport the variables to the create action? They are brought into the new action via URL variables (/posts/new?quoted=11&reply_to=8, for example).

Comment: Add them to the form as hidden_field_tag for example ... so when the form submits, it carries onto the `create` action ... or add them directly to the form_for like `form_for @post, :url => {:action => :create, :quoted => params[:quoted], :reply_to => params[:reply_to]}`

Comment: I dropped them into the form_for, which works great! Thank you!